# Curl-like monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, curl, functional-programming, monads

I am looking for a monad transformer that I can use to make HTTP (et al) kinds of requests/responses.  Similar in purpose to the cURL command line tool. [EDITED]

Comment: What's a "curl-like" operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's the [curl](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/curl/latest/doc/html/Network-Curl.html) package, which uses the `IO` monad.

Comment: I'm not opposed to this approach of binding to libcurl, but I am interested to know if there is a monad transformer that I can use to do this.  Granted one could make one using the curl package you mentioned, but I don't want to reinvent any wheels ;)

Comment: @ReubenPeter-Paul It would help if you explained why you need it to be a monad transformer.